# Create a Hibernate Entity that is not associated with a table

Tags: hibernate, jpa

I am trying to create an Entity that its fields are not specific to a table but to a query. For example:

```
@Entity
class MyEntity{
    @column("bookTitle ")
    private String bookTitle;

    @Column("rating ")
    private Double rating;

    @Column("sum")
    private Integer sum;
}
```

these fields are not columns of any table but yet I want:
SELECT o1.bookName AS bookTitle, o2.rate AS rating, o3.totalNumber AS sum...

entityManager.createQuery(my above query, MyEntity.class) should return a class of type MyEntity as expected

Unfortunately, Hibernate complains " Column not found".
In EclipseLink, or Toplink it's working fine. Besides, in my opinion an Entity should not be associated to a particular table but should hold a set of columns that are collected randomly.

Any Idea?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot map a select with an @Entity using Hibernate/JPA but you can do this :

```
public class MyEntity{

    private String bookTitle;
    private Double rating;
    private Integer sum;

    public MyEntity(String bookTitle, Double rating, Integer sum) {
         this.bookTitle = bookTitle;
         this.sum = rating;
         this.sum = sum;
    }
}
```

Then you use the following HQL :

```
select new package.MyEntity(o1.bookName, o2.rate, o3.totalNumber) from something where
```

Another solution would be to create a view and map the @Entity to the view.

Comment: BTW, it is possible to declare new columns inside a hibernate entity that do not reside on any table, as long as your query 'selects' them. In other words hibernate will complain only if you mapped an entity field and your select does not include this field